# The type GridCell is not generic; it cannot be parameterized with arguments <GridCell>. While creating a list

Tags: java, repast-simphony

I am novice in java and repast. I am trying to create a list of Grid cells (grid cells) of type gridcells (valuelayer cells) but I keep getting the error "The type GridCell is not generic; it cannot be parameterized with arguments "

How do I fix this?

```
package tester;

import java.util.List;

import repast.simphony.context.Context;
import repast.simphony.engine.environment.RunEnvironment;
import repast.simphony.engine.schedule.ScheduledMethod;
import repast.simphony.parameter.Parameters;
//import repast.simphony.query.space.grid.GridCell;
import repast.simphony.query.space.grid.GridCellNgh;
import repast.simphony.space.grid.Grid;
import repast.simphony.space.grid.GridPoint;
import repast.simphony.valueLayer.AbstractGridFunction;
import repast.simphony.valueLayer.BufferedGridValueLayer;
import repast.simphony.valueLayer.BufferedGridValueLayer.Buffer;
import repast.simphony.valueLayer.GridCell;
import repast.simphony.valueLayer.MaxGridFunction;
import repast.simphony.valueLayer.MinGridFunction;

            private void Move() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                BufferedGridValueLayer heat = (BufferedGridValueLayer) context.getValueLayer("Heat Layer");
                Grid <Object> grid = (Grid <Object>) context.getProjection("Insulation Grid");

                //Get the Grid Location of this insulation unit.
                GridPoint pt = grid.getLocation(this);

                //Use the GridCellNgh to retrieve the list of of Gridcells (grid) contianing Gridcells (valueLayergrid). 
                GridCellNgh <GridCell> nghCreator = new GridCellNgh <GridCell> (grid, pt, GridCell.class, 1, 1);


                List <GridCell <GridCell>> gridCells = nghCreator.getNeighborhood(true);
            }
```

Comment: Does the example require all the imports, can any be trimmed?

Comment: @JamesK I have only copied a part of the code. There are other parts of the code which need the imports in order to work.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Issue is with the last line. `GridCell` is not generic, so you cannot do `GridCell<GridCell>`. Use just `List<GridCell>`

Comment: @warmoverflow Many thanks for the suggestion, I had already tried your suggestion before posting this question. It did not help in resolving the issue. I then decided to manually check my neighbourhood which worked.

Answer (score 1):

There is some confusion because there are two GridCell classes in the Repast API.

`GridCellNgh.getNeighborhood(true)` returns type `repast.simphony.query.space.grid.GridCell<T>` which is a container for agents located at a specific grid location.  The `GridCellNgh` class is meant for retrieving these types of grid cells based on the type of agent classes and will not work for ValueLayer `repast.simphony.valueLayer.GridCell` objects.

`GridCellNgh` can be used to get the list of GridPoints from which you can get the associated `GridCell` via `GridCell.getPoint()`, however this assumes that all of the surrounding grid locations are filled with the agent class passed into `GridCellNgh` constructor which is only practical when the Grid is completely filled with agents.

I would suggest simply using `GridPoint pt = grid.getLocation(this)` as you currently do to get the center point and then just access the value layer based on the center x,y at each x+/-1, y+/-1 that makes up the Moore neighborhood.